# laravel webpack compile all sass files into single SASS file

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

I want laravel webpack to compile app.scss file into single **scss** (not css) file. This generated file will later process using `scssphp`

Ideally the generated output will be with scss extension and not sass as scssphp can process only scss files

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this package [`scss-bundle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-bundle)